# Cannot run the project on a local server, shows me files in the directory instead of app

Tags: python, server, project, pyramid

I'm currently running into a problem regarding a python web-app (using Pyramid framework), which I'm not able to start or run, due to multiple issues. I'll leave the github link for more information: https://github.com/sayoun/pyvac

First of all, I have  encountered an error:

```
installing the requirements for this project "Package requirements not satisfied" for the following apps:
 - Pillow==2.2.2
 - Criptacular==1.4.1
 - lxml==3.3.2
 - Python-ldap==2.4.14
 - Repoze.lru==0.6
 - simplejson==2.6.2
 - vobject==0.6.6
```

This might lead to the problem that i am not able to set up the `localhost` server. Though I  have not tried the commands left by the developer of that application, as seemingly the virtual environment does not accept the respective commands (either they don't exist or they are not applicable for PyCharm). Therefore I dug my head in too much information I don't yet understand, that's why I need your guys' help. I'm using Python version 3.5.0 and PyCharm 2018.1.2 Community edition, did update Pip from 9.0.1 as required by the project to pip 10.0.1 without any results.

Comment: did you `python setup.py` from the project you send in the OP ? did you try to install doing something like `pip install Pillow==2.2.2` etc... ? Some compatility problem have been report between some package and pyCharm 2018 did you try with pyCharm 216 for example ?

Comment: "seemingly the virtual environment does not accept the respective commands" What commands? What command did you use to create a virtual environment? What command did you use to install your application? Assuming you followed [these commands in the readme](https://github.com/sayoun/pyvac#getting-started) did you first set an environment variable `export venv=/path/to/virtualenvironment`?